# Installing SharePoint Framework Extensions Online

Tags: sharepoint-online, powershell, pnp-powershell

I'm trying to install SharePoint Framework Extensions from [here](https://github.com/SharePoint/sp-starter-kit#sharepoint-framework-extensions). However, I have no clue sadly on how to convert the JSON to SSPKG file so that I can upload to app catalog.
I have checked SharePoint documentation however I could not find how to convert existing JSON setup to SSPKG file.
Thank you for the help in advance.

Comment: I already deployed the SSPKG file from sp-starter-kit but it does not include the 'AlertNotifications' SPFx

Answer (score 0):

You can find the sppkg file of sp-starter-kit [here](https://github.com/SharePoint/sp-starter-kit/blob/master/package/sharepoint-starter-kit.sppkg)

If you want to know how to generate sppkg file from code you can follow [this guide](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/spfx/extensions/get-started/build-a-hello-world-extension)

Answer (score 0):

Suppose you mean site design json schema such as [associateExtension](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/declarative-customization/site-design-json-schema#register-an-extension)

You could use SharePoint Online Management Shell to do it.

https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/declarative-customization/site-design-powershell

One demo thread.

https://drewmadelung.com/powershell-for-sharepoint-site-designs-site-scripts/